# Authboss with Database

Tags: database, authentication, go

I just started learning Go a couple weeks ago, and I want to try and implement a kind of authentication system for a web server. Now, I found [authboss](https://github.com/go-authboss/authboss) which seems like a perfect solution except I don't understand how to integrate it with a traditional database. It seems like it just stores everything in its own memory which is a nightmare if the server crashes or needs to be restarted. That having been said, does anyone have any ideas, thoughts, or recommendations?

Comment: Just quickly reading trough the documentation, it look like they support the concept of storers (https://github.com/go-authboss/authboss#storers). If you find/implement yourself a stored for database (or any other persistent storage) then you should be fine.

Comment: And it seems to be pretty dormant. So be prepared that you might have to write bug fixes yourself.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: As @defectus mentioned, you will typically implement a Storer to store/retrieve your user accounts. But even when using the complementaray https://github.com/volatiletech/authboss-clientstate implementations of CookieStorer and SessionStorer, you will be storing session info in Gorilla "secure cookies" on the user browser, not preserving them within the site: for that you will need to build your own SessionStorer using your DB of choice to load/save the session so it can be shared across your server instances and used outside the request cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To use authboss authentication with a database backend you need to write a 'storer' implementation. There aren't very many database storers readily available (at least I haven't been able to find them).
2. Example authentication implementations with a database backend:

   - http://www.josephspurrier.com/go-web-app-example/ (Uses MySQL or Postgres)
   - https://blue-jay.github.io/ An updated version of the above implementation. Looks very promising.
   - https://github.com/qor/auth (Uses GORM)

Based on the number of stars on github, authboss is the most popular.

Of course, there are also commercial options, e.g. https://auth0.com/blog/authentication-in-golang/

A long list of available authentication libraries and frameworks can be found here: https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#authentication-and-oauth